# rigid body collision happening above passive scaled landscape surface

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Here is a video reproducing the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYkP81IXZX4

I scaled a landscape a lot (x500) then rigid body collision happens above the passive landscape instead of right on its surface. Apply all transforms does not solve the issue.

Comment: for the rigid body / passive, what does it give if you choose shape > mesh?

Comment: it fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ground choose *Shape > Mesh*